# set checkbox checked in jquery data table using json

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am loading y jquery data table using json data as such

```
$.each(data.myobjects, function( intIndex, user ){
    $('#myTable').dataTable().fnAddData([ user.Name,user.superAdmin,user.LUA]);
});
```

The columns `superAdmmin` and 'LUA` are checkbox columns

Based on data I want to set the checked to true else false.

My data for these 2 columns in the json string are set to either true or false

The check box are defined

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
                {
                    "aTargets": [2],
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<input type=\"checkbox\" class="checkSuperAdmin">';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "aTargets": [3],
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<input type=\"checkbox\" class="checkLUA">';
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Where is the argument that causes them to check/uncheck?

Comment: try `return '<input type=\"checkbox\" class="checkLUA" '+(data[1] ? 'checked' : '')+'>';`

Comment: `user.superAdmin,user.LUA` in the `fnAddData` is what I assume could check or uncheck the box as those are set to `true/false`

Comment: Why would these checkboxes be checked? What argument(s)?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: you suggestion was my solution. Unsure as to how I can accept your comment as the answer

Comment: @user3865642 I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `data` to set the checked state like

```
return '<input type=\"checkbox\" class="checkLUA" ' + (data[1] ? 'checked' : '') + '>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways :

(1) In mRender you can check for the data and write HTML based on the data condition .

```
 return '<input type=\"checkbox\" class="checkLUA" '+(data[1] ? 'checked' : '')+'>'
```

(2)

```
 rowCallback: function ( row, data ) {
    // Set the checked state of the checkbox in the table
    $('input.editor-active', row).prop( 'checked', data.active == 1 );
    }
```

Put a class name like editor-active to the checkbox ... rowCallBack function will be called after rendering of each row . AFter rendering the data will be checked and the below code will check teh checkbox

```
$('input.editor-active', row).prop( 'checked', data.active == 1 );
```